# Investigating the role of Functional Load in Speech Recognition

Tags: phonology, speech-recognition

I am currently delving into the application of Stokes and Surendran’s Functional Load (FL) in the context of Dutch CVC (Consonant-Vowel-Consonant) words. Stokes and Surendran (2005) propose FL as a measure of the amount of information lost when a consonantal opposition is lost, with entropy serving as a key statistical measure in their approach.

My specific challenge revolves around calculating the functional load for the comparison of two words.

How can I effectively measure the relative loss of diversity when two words, each with distinct consonantal elements, are compared using Stokes and Surendran’s FL methodology?

**References**:

Stokes, S. F., & Surendran, D. (2005). Articulatory complexity, ambient frequency, and functional load as predictors of consonant development in children

Van Severen, L., Gillis, J. J. M., Molemans, I., Van den Berg, R., De Maeyer, S., & Gillis, S. (2013). The relation between order of acquisition, segmental frequency and function: the case of word-initial consonants in Dutch.